# passing two lambdas to a function

Tags: syntax, lambda, coffeescript

I am trying to pass 2 functions to a function with the first one returning an object.

Somehow the parser gets that 'wrong' and I don't know how to solve this issue.
I would prefer having it in a single line of code

My CS

```
foo (a, b) -> bar {gna: foo}, (a, b) -> a is b
```

The JS

```
foo(function(a, b) {
  return bar({
    gna: foo
  }, function(a, b) {
    return a === b;
  });
});
```

The expected JS

```
foo(
    function(a, b) {
      return bar({gna: foo});
    }, function(a, b) {
      return a === b;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping one or both of the anonymous functions in parentheses will disambiguate the syntax when the compiler guesses wrong:

```
foo ((a, b) -> bar { gna: foo }), (a, b) -> a is b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foo(
  (a, b) -> bar {gna: foo}
  (a, b) -> a is b
  (a, b) ->
    a += b
    a isnt b
  (a, b) -> a+b
)
```